# Разделение различных исключений

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне нужно "напечатать текст исключения и сообщение о наличии ffmpeg на ПК", сделал так:

```
try:
    cmd = "ffmpeg -nostdin -loglevel quiet -i input_file_name -ar 16000.0 -ac 1 -f s16le -"
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
except subprocess.SubprocessError as e:
    raise("Missing ffmpeg")
```

(говорят не правильно), может у кого то есть идеи?

Answer (score 0):

Если вам надо напечатать текст исключения, используйте `print(exception)`:

```
try:
    cmd = "ffmpeg -nostdin -loglevel quiet -i input_file_name -ar 16000.0 -ac 1 -f s16le -"
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
except subprocess.SubprocessError as e:
    print(e, "\nMessage: missing ffmpeg")
```

В `print` объект исключения приведётся к строке сообщения.

`raise` используется, чтобы вызвать исключение. Пример:

```
def func():
    raise Exception("My message")


try:
    func()
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
```

> My message